Movie about a guy refused by production company ends by killing his actors
I'm looking for the name of a movie in which a man wants to produce a film and all production companies he has contacted refused him. Then the guy decided to make a movie on his own and hire some actors. I think it starts as some kind of documentary.
After some time, he became crazy and started to kill all his actors because they are bad/don't do what he wants. 
From this point, it becomes gross and dirty. Like if every murder have to respect some sort of process : killing, raping, burying.
I think it was released in the 2000s. 
Edit (some more details) :
It's probably an american film but not so sure. I'm quite sure most (if not all) of the film is made "hand-held camera" (like a found foutage).
I can't remember a lot, I know most of the scenes was disturbing. Like drilling a hole in a head to perform the second part of the process explained before. It was probably rated R or X on its released.  

We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
